# Align by relations of different width

Tags: vertical-alignment, align

I am typesetting some expressions using the `align` environment given by LaTeX's math mode. Here my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        a &= b \\
          &\Longrightarrow c \\
          &= d
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

It would be nice if the expressions on the right side of each relation will be aligned vertically

```
a  =  b
  ==> c
   =  d
```

just by using tools from the `align` environment – i.e. not by using any sort of arrays, or by manually inserting whitespace like `\quad` and so on. It does not matter to me in which manner the relations will be positioned (left-aligned, centered ...), as long as it looks *good*.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here comes the not so minimal example in order to have a feeling which solution might look better than others.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\app}[2]{#1~#2}
\newcommand{\papp}[2]{\left(#1~#2\right)}
\newcommand{\sub}[2]{\left[#1\middle/#2\right]}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        \app{(\lambda a.\lambda b.\app{\papp{a}{b}}{a})}{F}
                &= \app{(\lambda a.\lambda b.\app{\papp{a}{b}}{a})}{(\lambda x.\lambda y.y)} \\
                &\Rightarrow_{\beta} \lambda b.(\app{\papp{a}{b}}{a})\sub{\lambda x.\lambda y.y}{a} \\
                &= \lambda b.\papp{\papp{a}{b}\sub{\lambda x.\lambda y.y}{a}}{a\sub{\lambda x.\lambda y.y}{a}}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would you like to make a “real world” example?

Comment: @egreg: Now I added another example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest an approach based on the `eqparbox` package, which allows for a simple syntax: I define an `\alignedsymbols` command, with a mandatory argument (the math symbol to be aligned), and the alignment as an optional argument: `c, l, r`; c is the default. A simple `align` environment will do:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand\alignsymbols[2][c]{\mathrel{\eqmakebox[S][#1]{$#2$}}{}} % optional argument is c (default), l or r

\begin{document}

    \begin{align*}
          a & \alignsymbols{=}b & a & \alignsymbols[l]{=}b & a & \alignsymbols[r]{=} b \\%
           & \alignsymbols{\Longrightarrow}c & & \alignsymbols[l]{\Longrightarrow}c & & \alignsymbols[r]{\Longrightarrow}c \\%
           & \alignsymbols{>}d & & \alignsymbols[l]{>}d & & \alignsymbols[r]{>}d
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I pasted your code completely and I'm getting 100 compile errors. Here's a preview:

Undefined control sequence     \end{align*}
Missing } inserted     \end{align*}
Missing } inserted     \end{align*}
Missing } inserted     \end{align*}
Extra }, or forgotten $     \end{align*}
Extra }, or forgotten $     \end{align*}
Missing { inserted     \end{align*}
Undefined control sequence     \end{align*}
Missing } inserted     \end{align*}
Missing } inserted     \end{align*}
Missing } inserted     \end{align*}
Extra }, or forgotten $     \end{align*}
...

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post a minimal (non)working code? Maybe there are incompatibilities with other packages you load.

Comment: I copied your MWE into a new file and it's not working. I'm using Tex Live 2009/Debian.

Comment: OK, but did you try to compile my code alone? If there's no problem, there is something in the rest of you code that conflicts mine (or the `eqparbox` package). If there is a problem, perhaps your distribution is too old.

Comment: Yep, I'm just using your code alone. So I have to consider upgrading my distribution.

Comment: With Tex Live 2012 your solution finally works!

Comment: Fine. But why don't install TeX Live 2014, or even 2015? Several important  packages have changed in depth since then.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `alignat*` that has advantages over `array`; the only possible alignment I see for the relation symbols is to their left, or the equals signs will appear hanging from nowhere.

I also suggest some changes to your macros, using `\papp[\big]` in the last line so that the outer parentheses will increase their size (which they don't do with `\left` and `\right`).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\newcommand{\app}[2]{#1\mspace{6mu}#2}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\papp}[2]{(}{)}{%
  #1\mspace{6mu}#2%
}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\sub}[2]{[}{]}{%
  #1\delimsize/#2%
}

\newcommand{\lrel}[1]{#1{}&&}


\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
\app{(\lambda a.\lambda b.\app{\papp{a}{b}}{a})}{F}
  &\lrel{=} \app{(\lambda a.\lambda b.\app{\papp{a}{b}}{a})}{(\lambda x.\lambda y.y)} \\
  &\lrel{\Rightarrow_{\beta}} \lambda b.(\app{\papp{a}{b}}{a})\sub{\lambda x.\lambda y.y}{a} \\
  &\lrel{=} \lambda b.\papp[\big]{\papp{a}{b}\sub{\lambda x.\lambda y.y}{a}}{a\sub{\lambda x.\lambda y.y}{a}}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to highlight (for other readers), that your macro improvements make use of the package `mathtools` which isn't included within Tex Live (2009) by default. Anyway: Thanks for doing so!

Comment: @user3389669 Upgrading to TL 2015 is in order. `;-)`

Comment: Will Tex Live 2012 be sufficient? There's a PPA for my OS (Ubuntu 12.04) which helps me to avoid setting up a local distribution.

Comment: @user3389669 It's vastly outdated as well, but surely contains `mathtools`.

Comment: I now can confirm that Tex Live 2012 is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

`alignat` allows to specify the horizontal alignment 'width' (well, the number of equation columns rather)

See the difference between the original and the `alignat*` version.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    Original version with \verb+align*+
    \begin{align*}
          a &=               b  \\
           &\Longrightarrow c \\
           &= d
    \end{align*}

 Version with \verb+alignat*+
    \begin{alignat*}{2}
          a &=               & b  \\
           &\Longrightarrow{} &c \\
           &= &d
    \end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution comes quite near to what I would expect, but the space between `\Longrightarrow` and `c` is too small in my perception.

Comment: Well, add a `\quad` after the `&` for the `c` line ;-)

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: you should add `{}` after `\Longrightarrow`.

Comment: @Bernard: Done, thanks for the tip -- I don't use math environments/typesetting very often

Comment: maybe the good old eqnarray is in order?

Answer (score 0):

## Relational symbol right aligned

The following example moves the `\Longrightarrow` to the left using the white space there. It is assumed, that the real world example will have more than just a `a` on the left side, also the arrow is probably annotated, otherwise `\Rightarrow` will look much better.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        a &= b \\
          &\mathrel{\hphantom{=}\llap{$\Longrightarrow$}} c \\
          &= d
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

## Relational symbol centered

Since the equations aren't numbered, the equation system can also be set via an `array`. The relational symbol is put in the middle column and the spacing around is explicitly set with `\;`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{gather*}
    \begin{array}{@{}r@{\;}c@{\;}l@{}}
        a &=& b \\
          &\Longrightarrow& c\\
          &=& d
    \end{array}
  \end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result centered]

The cells are set in `\textstyle`, but `\displaystyle` can be explicitly specified (not relevant for the simple variables here):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{gather*}
    \begin{array}{
      @{}
      >{\displaystyle}r
      @{\;}>{\displaystyle}c@{\;}
      >{\displaystyle}l@{}
    } 
      a &=& b \\  
      &\Longrightarrow& c\\    
      &=& d          
    \end{array}
  \end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have tested your _Relational symbol right aligned_ approach and even in the real example it does not meet my taste. The _Relational symbol centered_ approach seems to do what I want, but:
1. Is there no other way than using an array?
2. If not, is there a more abstract solution, like a package or a (user defined) command, which will save me writing these additional 7 lines every time?

Comment: @user3389669 There is `\newenvironment`, ...

Comment: eqnarray seems to be the obvious solution.